# Trouble With Z-Index (Over Under Over)

Tags: html, css

So I have three relatively positioned divs and one fixed element.  The idea is the fixed element is visible in the middle div, and not in the top or bottom div.

```
#top {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:40vh;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
#middle {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:60vh;
    background-image: asset-url('foo.png');

    p {
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 200%;
        text-shadow: 3px #eee;
    }
    z-index:-10;
}
#bottom {
    position:relative;
    background-image: asset-url('bar.png');
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:50vh;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

    z-index:999;
}
```

And my fixed element is this:

```
#fixedEle {
position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:5%;
    z-index:2;
    transform: translate(00%, -50%);
    img {
        height:80%;
        width:80%;
    }
}
```

Right now, the fixed element is Under #Top (as intended) Above #Middle (as intended) and Above #Bottom (UNINTENDED!)  The middle div is still on top of the bottom, but I'm not sure why, everything is positioned relatively and the z-indexes are where they should be. High, low, high.

**How can I get the bottom div below the middle and thus hide the fixed element?**

Update: Html

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="text1">
        <p data-start='opacity: 0' 
        data-30p-start='opacity: 1'>Yada yada yada this that and some other junkYada yada yada this that and some other junkYada yada yada this that and some other junkYada yada yada this that and some other junkYada yada yada this that and some other junkYada yada yada this that and some other junkYada yada yada this that and some other junk</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="middle">
    <div id="fixed">
        <%=image_tag ('fixed_logo.png')  %>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">

</div>
```

Comment: can you post your HTML or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I added html above.  Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

One Hour Later: One of the images I was working with had an alpha channel and was partially transparent, so it appeared as though the fixedEle wasn't behind the coverEle, though it was.

If you're dealing with z-index and having problems, **Make Sure You're Not Trying to Hide an Item Behind a Transparent Element!**

Answer (score -1):

I would try possibly reordering the order of the divs in your html and play with the z-indices of them to get the desired sort order.